# Recursive string reverse function

Tags: c, strings, recursion

I'm studying C on K&R and now I'm facing a recursion exercise that states:

> Write a recursive version of the function reverse(s), which reverses the string `s` in place.

I've written the code below and I'm pretty sure that it works.  I'll be glad to receive some critiques about it.

**Reverse function:**

```
/* reverse: reverse string s in place */
void reverse(char s[])
{
    static int i, j = 0;
    int c;

    if (i == 0) {
        i = 0;
        j = strlen(s)-1;
    }
    c = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = c;
    i++;
    j--;
    while(i < j)
        reverse(s);
}
```

**Main:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 100

void reverse(char s[]);

int main(void)
{
    char s[MAXLINE] = "foo bar baz";

    reverse(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, you can't find a similar solution? The solution [on that page from David Kachlon](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_4:Exercise_13) is pretty much the same, except that he does not use static variables and no while-loop.

Comment: That's right. Thank you.
Should I delete my question since it isn't very useful?

Comment: If you don't need it anymore now, then yes. If you still want a review, leave it here but edit it.

Comment: Probably not worth an answer but I don't think you really need to set `0` to `i` when `i == 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this is recursive, it entirely misses the point.  As the while loop will only ever execute once (because the function it calls only returns when `i < j` it could just as well have been an if, and thus all you've got is tail-recursion.

What you have is equivalent to the following, but impossible to call twice and maybe less efficient:

```
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1;
    int c;
    while (i < j) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

That's obviously not recursive.  The way you'd do it recursively is always swap the outer two characters of the string and then pass pointers to the beginning and end of a substring along.

Apart from that, you're initialising `j` but not `i`, which makes little sense: both will be 0 initially anyway, so at least be consistent.  You're also not using `MAXLINE`, so you might as well get rid of it (if C allows it).  You're also not checking for a `NULL` being passed in.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why it **entirely** misses the point?

Comment: @cimere: Because it doesn't function recurvively.  The call you have could be replaced with a goto and nothing would change.  By the way, Jerry's suggestion is better than mine (mine is also tail-recursion).

Comment: I disagree, the function as written is properly recursive.  Incidentally, it is not tail recursive because the recursive call is in a while statement.  He shouldn't have used a `while` instead of an `if` and he should have used arguments instead of static variables (the `if (i == 0)` bug makes it a one shot function), but that doesn't make the function non recursive.

Answer (score 5):

Simple worked example of Anton's suggestion:

```
void reverse_rec(char *begin, char *end)
{
    if (begin < end) {
        char swp = *begin;
        *begin = *end;
        *end = swp;
        reverse_rec(begin+1, end-1);
    }
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
    if (s)
        reverse_rec(s, s+strlen(s)-1);
}
```

Note that you don't need a `while`, because `recurse_rec` stops recursing when `begin >= end`.

Comment: Helper function should be declared `static`.

Comment: I think, you meant to subtract 1 from `end` rather than adding.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work if you call reverse () more than once in one run of program:

```
char s[MAXLINE] = "foo bar baz";
reverse(s);
printf("%s\n", s);     // get "zab rab oof"
reverse(s);
printf("%s\n", s);     // get "zab rab oof"
```

This happens because of your use of static variables in function.